# Associating two arrays in an RDD by index

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD contains two arrays for each row `RDD[(Array[Int], Array[Double])]`. For each row, the two arrays have similar size of `n`. However, every row has different size of `n`, and `n` could be up to 200. The sample data is as follows:

```
(Array(1, 3, 5), Array(1.0, 1.0, 2.0))
(Array(6, 3, 1, 9), Array(2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0))
(Array(2, 4), Array(1.0, 3.0))
. . .
```

I want to combine between those two arrays according to the index for each line. So, the expected output is as follows:

```
((1,1.0), (3,1.0), (5,2.0))
((6,2.0), (3,1.0), (1,2.0), (9,1.0))
((2,1.0), (4,3.0))
```

This is my code:

```
val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq( (Array(1, 3, 5),Array(1.0, 1.0, 2.0)), (Array(6, 3, 1,9),Array(2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0)) , (Array(2, 4),Array(1.0, 3.0)) ) )
val pairArr = data.map{x =>
  (x._1(0), x._2(0))
}
//pairArr: Array((1,1.0), (6,2.0), (2,1.0))
```

This code only takes the value of the first index in each row. 
Can anybody give me direction how to get the expected output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `zip` the two elements in each tuple:

```
data.map(x => x._1.zip(x._2)).collect
// res1: Array[Array[(Int, Double)]] = Array(Array((1,1.0), (3,1.0), (5,2.0)), Array((6,2.0), (3,1.0), (1,2.0), (9,1.0)), Array((2,1.0), (4,3.0)))
```

Or with pattern matching:

```
data.map{ case (x, y) => x.zip(y) }.collect
// res0: Array[Array[(Int, Double)]] = Array(Array((1,1.0), (3,1.0), (5,2.0)), Array((6,2.0), (3,1.0), (1,2.0), (9,1.0)), Array((2,1.0), (4,3.0)))
```